# Wrong container based on right image

Tags: docker

My image is correct (I know it because of the `new.txt` file):

```
» docker run --rm -it webserverint_nginx bash
root@5f1529af301e:/# ls www/static/
ai  new.txt  shp  spp
```

The container is wrong:

```
» docker exec -it webserverint_nginx_1 bash
root@6cb9e4be9edf:/# ls www/static/
ai  shp  spp
```

How is this possible? The `Dockerfile` does not apply any changes to `/www/static`!!

The is the `Dockerfile` used to build the `webserverint_nginx` image used by the `webserverint_nginx_1` container:

```
FROM registry.mine/webserver:int

ADD sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

ADD ssl/int/ /etc/nginx/ssl/

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The `Dockerfile` used to build the base image (`registry.mine/webserver:int`) is:

```
FROM nginx:1.12

ADD static/ /www/static/
```

These are the available images:

```
» docker images | grep webserver
webserverint_nginx            latest              321a1812787e        4 minutes ago       236MB
registry.mine/webserver       int                 dc1d5660d716        22 minutes ago      236MB
```

And this is the container:

```
» docker ps | grep webserver
6cb9e4be9edf        webserverint_nginx      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp              webserverint_nginx_1
```

Comment: Can you also post the `command` you are using for your webserver container?

Comment: @gravetii it is based on `nginx:1.12` (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)

Comment: Can't really imagine this happening. Can you try removing all the containers and starting a new container and then checking the folder?

Comment: Adding the exact `docker build` and `docker run` commands to reproduce this would be helpful.  (Docker volumes could cause behavior like this, but that'd be a detail of `docker run` you haven't shown.)

Comment: @DavidMaze oooops, right. I had a named volume mounted (via docker compose). Too many moving parts ...